# Nodejs, is better have a lot of same require or use a handle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, module

Image this esctructure:

```
- app.js
- core/
  - service_1.js
  - service_2.js
  - service_3.js
  - service_4.js
  - service_5.js
- modules/
  - module_1.js
  - module_2.js
  - module_3.js
```

The **app.js** uses the 3 modules, so the code of the app is:

```
var m1 = require('./modules/module_1'); 
var m2 = require('./modules/module_2'); 
var m3 = require('./modules/module_3'); 

m1.exec();
m2.exec();
m3.exec();
```

And **each model** uses all the services, so they need:

```
var s1 = require('./../core/service_1'); 
var s2 = require('./../core/service_2'); 
var s3 = require('./../core/service_3'); 
var s4 = require('./../core/service_3'); 
var s5 = require('./../core/service_3'); 

// some stuff...
```

So, I need to know if this is the best way to handle that or maybe do a "serviceManager" like:

**app.js**

```
var m1 = require('./modules/module_1'); 
var m2 = require('./modules/module_2'); 
var m3 = require('./modules/module_3');

var serviceManager = {
  service_1 : require('./core/service_1'),
  service_2 : require('./core/service_2'),
  service_3 : require('./core/service_3'),
  service_4 : require('./core/service_4'),
  service_5 : require('./core/service_5')
};

m1.load(serviceManager);
m2.load(serviceManager);
m3.load(serviceManager);

m1.exec();
m2.exec();
m3.exec();
```

And **each model** I put:

```
var serviceManager = null;

exports.load = function(services) {
  serviceManager = services;
}

// some stuff...
```

What is the best if I gonna use that class in almost all my files?

a) Get a lot of 'require'.

b) A handle to put 'require' only one time.

c) Another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a lot of `require`s. It does not matter, because Node.js caches the modules after first load.

From the Node.js docs:

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

Comment: Oh! So is equally if I put alot or a handle to reduce the write the same a lot?

Comment: Yes, it is. The "handler solution" would result in slightly more "memory usage" because you are holding a reference to the modules too, but this argument is negligible.

Comment: Aham! Thanks for your answer! I will use the two modes, depending on the situation o:

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection is really good for this. I've used and recommend [insulin](https://github.com/benbotto/insulin).  This makes it very easy to load each of your modules in the dependency injection container and then just name dependencies in the modules you write.

You might do something like the following:

```
'use strict';
require('insulin').factory('myService', myServiceFactoryFunction);

function myServiceFactoryFunction(dependencyOne, dependencyTwo) {
  // Do something with your dependencies.
}
```

This way you require once at the top of the file and never have to do it again in that file.

As mentioned in one of the other answers, node caches everything required, so each time you require the injection container, you get the same one.  This makes it very quick and easy to build your app without either having to require things everywhere or pass things around.

Later, to get the module you created above you would just do the following where it's needed:

```
'use strict';
require('insulin').factory('mySecondService', mySecondServiceFactoryFunction);

function mySecondServiceFactoryFunction(myService) {
  // myService is now available in this module
}
```

Insulin, as with most other dependency injectors you might use has other methods if you for some reason don't want to or can't rely on injection in some part of your application. You could do something like:

```
const insulin = require('insulin');
const myDependency = insulin.get('someModule');
```

where needed.

The best part about this to me is that the code becomes really clean and it's easy to tell what the dependencies are for a given file just by looking at the arguments passed to the factory function.